# SPFx- Routes vs toggling visiblity

Tags: spfx, reactjs

I have a requirement in which I have to hide the component from the page and load a new component.

Which one is the preferred approach:

1. Toggling the visibility of component
2. Using routes

Answer (score 3):

For the same problem I used a different approach. 2 child components had button click event which gave a call back to a common parent component.

In parent component I using switch case to decide which child component to display next.

Answer (score 0):

`ReactDom.render()` will unload the existing component and load the new one.